# Spring @WebFilter pattern is not matching @Controller pattern

Tags: spring-mvc

I've made a Gist to try to illustrate the issue I'm trying to solve:

https://gist.github.com/jmcgill-public/e05d4378049296f05691

I have a Spring `@Controller` with a `@RequestMapping` value, and a `@WebFilter` with a urlPattern to match. The Filter initializes, but is not executed on the corresponding Controller method. 
If I change the Filter's urlPattern to "/*", the Filter does execute (for every request).

Why doesn't it execute for these matching urls?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, if that's okay.

The answer is, the urlPattern in a @WebFilter must be the request URL according to HTTP, meaning it must include any context path preceding the @Controller's @RequestMapping path.

This is inconvenient, but I didn't understand that @WebFilters are javax.servlet.annotations, not org.springframework annotations.  So I was mixing up layers and mixing framework technologies.